# Why this Simple For Loop doesn't work?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Can anybody please tell me why this simple  for loop won't work?
For example, if I type in 5, nothing would come out.

```
int Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = Num2; i < 1; i--) {
    Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", i);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to count backwards with this loop? If so, your continue condition never triggers.

Comment: Because 5 > 1 and the for loop terminate immediately

Comment: It's not terribly important, but… what language?

Comment: @deceze: Looks like C# to me.

Answer (score 6):

Your condition reads "i is less than 1". You probably meant "i is greater than zero".

```
for (int i = Num2; i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: I Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you are comparing `5 < 1` cause `False` result.

You need to change the `condition` :-

```
int Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = Num2; i > 0; i--) {
    Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", i);
}
```

Or Pass the `input` `less than` 1 like 0,-1,... which leads your `program` to `infinite` `loop`.

```
int Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = Num2; i < 1; i--) {
    Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//int Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //
    //for (int i = Num2; i < 1; i--) {
     //   Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", i);
    //}
```

here is you are doing wrong **i < 1** change it to **i >1**

```
 int Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    
      for (int i = Num2; i > 1; i--)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Test{0}", i);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't ever recommend `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bad anti-pattern. Especially in this case when no exception is being raised.

Comment: His dev environment will do that out of the box. Writing `catch (Exception ex)` is a way of hiding bugs and making programming more difficult.

Comment: Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks i will go through that but he i was going according to his word that nothing would come out. so i were suggested that i will not do that again